# Nested structures in Lisp

Tags: struct, lisp, nested, common-lisp, field

I'm starting with Lisp and I need to know if it is possible to use nested structures. Here is my try:

```
(defstruct casilla i j)
(defstruct tablero caballo reina t1 t2)

(defparameter *estado-inicial*
  (make-tablero :caballo (make-casilla :i 1 :j 1)
                :reina   (make-casilla :i 5 :j 4)
                :t1      (make-casilla :i 3 :j 5)
                :t2      (make-casilla :i 4 :j 5)))
```

And if I have to access to the field `i`:

```
(defun es-estado-final (estado)
  (and (= (caballo-casilla-i estado) 3)
       (= (caballo-casilla-j estado) 1)))
```

Is that right? It seems it isn't because `caballo-casilla-i` is undefined.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For structs your Lisp environment created for you automatically the accessors `tablero-caballo` and `casilla-i`. To combine them you need to use `(casilla-i (tablero-caballo estado))`. Obviously, you can roll out your own accessor function:

```
(defun caballo-casilla-i (estado)
  (casilla-i (tablero-caballo estado)))
```

Also you can `(declaim (inline caballo-casilla-i))` to not waste additional function calls.

Comment: The correct answer is:

`(defun caballo-casilla-j (estado)
  (casilla-j (tablero-caballo estado)))`